# VB.NET Key Pressing?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple background program that runs in the background using VB.NET to change anything I type to a hexadecimal value. For example, if I'm writing an email and I press "h" then it would erase the "h" and replace it with it's hexadecimal value(h's is 68). I have no clue how to do this could someone please explain?

Comment: It's a simplistic question, but I gotta ask: why the downvotes, folks?

Comment: @RobPerkins: my guess is no signs of research effort.

Comment: Hopefully my answer left enough for research effort.

Comment: @RobPerkins: It's probably being downvoted because a) it's a meaningless question ("how do I do something that makes my keyboard totally useless like turning all letters into hex values?") that will likely not be very useful to future readers here, and b) because it shows absolutely no effort to solve it first. (I didn't downvote, but I am voting to close it as "not a real question" for those reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're looking for the `Asc()` and `AscW()` functions in Visual Basic. Combine that with `String.Format()` to display the number as a hexadecimal value, and key it all off a keypress event of some kind.

For best results, stick with WinForms over WPF for such an app.

If what you want is to make the thing run in the background over literally **everything** you may be out of luck; Windows' process separation and message passing systems will get completely in your way.